# ¿cual es la forma mas rápida de ejecutar código string de Javascript (eval, new Function o constructor)?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

He estado leyendo un poco sobre **Eval()**, que es una función que **ejecuta javascript a partir de un string**, pero que según es muy peligroso y consume muchos recursos, hasta que buscando alternativas, encontré dos muy interesantes y funcionan de igual manera, **new Function()** y **constructor.constructor()**.
Quisiera saber si hay otras alternativas o si estas ultimas dos son optimas para ejecutar strings de javascript.

Para ello muestro un ejemplo con la API **Highcharts.js**, donde en las tres opciones se ejecuta perfectamente, pero el foros dicen que **Eval()** no debería usarse. ¿que opinan?

```js
var grafica="Highcharts.chart(\"row3\", {chart: {type: \"bar\",height:1000},title: {text: \"HISTORICO DE PASES GENERADOS A LAS OFICINAS CORRESPONDIENTES\"},subtitle:{text:\"AÑO 2018\"},xAxis: {categories: [\"ADMINISTRACION\",\"ARCHIVO\",\"ASESORIA JURIDICA\",\"ATENCION AL CIUDADANO\",\"BIBLIOTECA\",\"CULTURA\",\"DEPORTE\",\"DESPACHO\",\"DIVISION DE COMUNINADES EDUCATIVAS\",\"DIVISION DE DOTACION LOGISTICA\",\"DIVISION DE GESTION INTERNA\",\"DIVISION DE JOVENES Y ADULTOS\",\"DIVISION DE NIÑOS, NIÑAS Y POBLACION CON NECESIDADES EDUCATIVAS ESPECIALES\",\"DIVISION DE SUPERVISION\",\"ESCUELA TECNICA\",\"FORMACION PERMANENTE\",\"GESTION HUMANA\",\"INFORMATICA\",\"PLANIFICACION\",\"PRENSA\",\"RECURSO PARA EL APRENDIZAJE\",\"REPRODUCCION\",\"SALA SITUACIONAL\",\"SEGURO SOCIAL\"],title: {text: null},labels:{style:{fontSize:\"12px\",color:\"#db1b32\"}}},yAxis: {min: 0,title: {text: \"NUMERO DE PASES\",align: \"high\"},labels: {overflow: \"justify\",style:{color:\"#db1b32\",fontSize:\"12px\"}}},tooltip: {valueSuffix: \" PASES\"},plotOptions: {bar: {dataLabels: {enabled: true}}},series: [{ name: \"PASES\",data: [66,17,10,36,8,9,12,20,15,33,28,22,26,46,63,25,13,52,18,41,47,89,5,61,74],dataLabels:{style:{fontSize:\"12px\"}}}],navigation: {menuStyle: {background: \"#E0E0E0\"}}});";

document.getElementById('eval').addEventListener('click',function(){eval(grafica);});
document.getElementById('newfunction').addEventListener('click',function(){new Function(grafica)();});
document.getElementById('constructor').addEventListener('click',function(){constructor.constructor(grafica)();});
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>¿cual es la forma mas rapida de ejecutar codigo String de Javascript?</h2>
<button id='eval'>Eval(stringCode);</button><br>
<button id='newfunction'>new Function(stringCode)();</button><br>
<button id='constructor'>constructor.constructor(stringCode)();</button>
<div id='row3'></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En temas de rendimiento: en ambos casos los strings han de ser *parseados* por el compilador antes de ser ejecutados. Las diferencias en favor de una forma u otra pueden depender de la implementación del intérprete (V8, Chakra, SpiderMonkey...), [aquí te dejo una prueba de rendimiento](https://jsperf.com/pablolozano/), mis resultados varían enormemente si uso Firefox o Edge.

En temas de seguridad, hay ligeras diferencias: eval tiene acceso a las variables globales y al contexto local, mientras que usando Function el código tiene acceso a las variables globales, pero el contexto es distinto.

En cualquier caso te aconsejo evitar su uso, es muy raro encontarte ante la necesidad de inyectar código desde un string en tu aplicación.

Comment: Es un string que construyo/concateno, de forma dinamica, en barra o columnas, entre otras cosas.
Pero veré la manera de no generarlo como string, sino hacer una función que haga eso, solo estaba experimentando y la verdad me sorprende las cosas que tiene javascript, nunca deja de asombrarme las muchas funciones que tiene.