# Reemplazar funcion Eval

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, java-ee

Tengo que reemplazar en una aplicación JEE (no la he creado yo) todas las apariciones de la función `eval()`. El motivo es dado tras realizar un análisis del código mediante una solución de medición de la calidad y la seguridad del software (Kiuwan), el cuál indica como una de las soluciones para mejorar las métricas, eliminar las apariciones de dicha función.

Según esto, se me plantean varios casos en los que no se muy bien cómo realizar el reemplazo. Me gustaría saber si los cambios que he hecho son correctos y en el caso en el que no sepa como hacerlo, me podáis orientar (las líneas con eval están comentadas):

**CASO 1**

```
edicionGrid = function(formid,nombregrid) {
    $("#Act_Buttons td:first").remove();
    //var gruposLocal = eval("grupos_" + nombregrid);
    var gruposLocal = (new Function('return ' + 'grupos_' + nombregrid))();
    ...
```

*Error*:

```
VM1089:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: grupos_evaluacion is not defined
...
```

**CASO 2**

```
myelemSelect = function(value, options) {
//Crea el elemento DOM para el tipo de campo MODCAMPO_SELECT
    var nombreCampo = options["name"]; 
    var select;
    var id = jQuery(idGridParaCombos).getGridParam('selrow');
    var valorSeleccionado;
    var rowData;
    if (id) {
        var rowData = jQuery(idGridParaCombos).getRowData(id);
        //valorSeleccionado = eval("rowData." + nombreCampo);
        valorSeleccionado = (new Function('return rowData.' + nombreCampo))();
    } else {        
        rowData = jQuery(idGridParaCombos).getRowData();
        if(rowData != '') {
            valorSeleccionado = value;
            //valorSeleccionado = eval("rowData[0]." + nombreCampo);
            valorSeleccionado = (new Function('return rowData[0].' + nombreCampo))();
        } 
    }
    ...
```

*Error*:

```
VM1089:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: rowData is not defined
...
```

**CASO 3**

```
for(var i = 0; i < opciones["colModel"].length ; i++) {
    if(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions != null) {
        if(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_element != undefined) {
            var evalFunction = opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_element = eval(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_element);
        }

        if(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_value != undefined) {
            opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_value = eval(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_value);
        }
    }
}
```

***Nota:*** En este caso no se como realizar el reemplazo.

**CASO 4**

```
if (isDefined("gridLoadComplete")) {
    gridLoadCompleteSoloLectura();
    //eval("gridLoadComplete();"); //Ejecuto loadcomplete propio de la pagina
    gridLoadComplete();
}
```

***Nota:*** Llamo directamente a la función. No se si es correcto.

**CASO 5**

```
//eval("$(\"#jqgh_" + nuevoString+ " .ui-icon-" + arOrden[i] + "\").removeClass(\"ui-state-disabled\");");
$("#jqgh_" + nuevoString + " .ui-icon-" + arOrden[i]).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

***Nota:*** En este caso, parece que funciona correctamente.

He puesto un ejemplo de cada uno de los casos en los que aparece la función `eval()` y me gustaría que me ayudarais o me digais si está bien hecho o no.

En otras apariciones he realizado el reemplazo y en principio parece que no da problemas, al igual que en los casos 4 y 5.

Gracias.

Comment: En tu tercer caso ¿Qué contienen custom_element y custom_value?

Comment: Y no utilices `new Function`, mientras que no es lo mismo que eval, es muy parecido. Prueba a usar `window["functionName"](arguments);` en tus llamadas como explican en [esta respuesta.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153883/cual-es-la-forma-mas-r%C3%A1pida-de-ejecutar-c%C3%B3digo-string-de-javascript-eval-new/153915#153915

Comment: custom_element y custom_value son propiedades del objeto editoptions que contienen strings. Había leído sobre esto del enlace, pero no lo termino de entender muy bien. Por ejemplo, en el caso 1, al ser una variable, como debería componerla y que contexto debería utilizar, ya que está dentro de una función? @Juliosor

Comment: @DevCodeG con `window` se refieren al objeto global del documento, por tanto sólo te hace falta el nombre de la función y que esté declarada en este ámbito general. Si no lo estuviera, el enlace explica cómo acceder a namespaces. Es decir, `window["grupos_" + nombregrid]();` debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiar la función eval por usar Function quizá haga que las métricas de Kiuwan den mejores valores, pero realmente no ganas casi nada, lo ideal sería modificar el código para que no haga uso de esa funcionalidad.

Entiendo que al ser el código heredado no quieras modificarlo mucho, pero lo lógico sería intentar refactorizar el código para eliminar la necesidad.

Opciones que se me ocurren:

**CASO 1**

```
edicionGrid = function(formid,nombregrid) {
    $("#Act_Buttons td:first").remove();
    var gruposLocal = eval("grupos_" + nombregrid); 
...
```

Si las variables con el prefijo `grupos_` son globales, eso significa que puedes acceder a ellas a través del objeto global `window`:

```
 var gruposLocal=window[`grupos_${nombregrid}`];
```

Si no son globales, crea un objeto que las incluya:

```
const global={};

global.grupos_loquesea= ...;
```

Y podrás acceder de la misma manera:

```
let gruposLocal=global[`grupos_${nombregrid}`];
```

```js
var unEjemplo='Hola';

console.log('Con eval()',eval('unEjemplo;'))

console.log('Con window:',window['unEjemplo']);


(function () {
  var unEjemplo2='Hola';

  console.log('Con eval()',eval('unEjemplo2;'))
  // Así no funciona, la variable es local a la función
  console.log('Con window:',window['unEjemplo2']);


})();

// Agupando las variables en una constante global
(function () {
  const global={};
  global.unEjemplo2='Prueba';
  
  console.log('Con global:',global['unEjemplo2']);


})()
```

**CASO 2**

Este es aún más sencillo, puesto que

```
valorSeleccionado = eval("rowData." + nombreCampo);
```

es equivalente a

```
valorSeleccionado = rowData[nombreCampo];
```

**CASO 3**

Este caso es un poco más complejo porque realmente es un código horrible en muchos sentidos: vas a a sustituir, como valor de un atributo, el nombre de una variable por el valor de esa variable:

```
    if(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_element != undefined) {
        var evalFunction = opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_element = eval(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_element);
    }

    if(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_value != undefined) {
        opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_value = eval(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_value);
    }
```

Pero se reduce de la misma manera que el **caso 1**:

```
    if(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_element != undefined) {
        const nombreVariable =opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_element;
        var evalFunction = opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_element = window[nombreVariable];
    }

    if(opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_value != undefined) {
        const nombreVariable2=opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_value;
        opciones["colModel"][i].editoptions.custom_value = window[nombreVariable2];
    }
```

Los casos 4 y 5 creo que funcionan bien tal y como los tienes

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, voy a intentar probar, como comentas, tengo que hacer los mínimos cambios así que voy a intentar cambiar lo menos posible @PabloLozano

Comment: Puedes pasarte por el [chat de SOes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) si quieres comentar dudas, por no extender demasiado los comentarios