# Ejecución de funciones dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Tratando de ser lo más resumido posible, si tengo el siguiente arreglo en Javascript

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {action: "doSetLibraryTreeData", data: Array(1)}
1: {action: "doSetSource", data: Array(3)}
2: {action: "doSetFunctionDefinitionList", data: Array(3)}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar dinamicamente cada una de las funciones "action" y pasarle el "data" como parámetro?

Es que quiero ejecutar un [batch de redux](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch) dada una respuesta de un Web Worker.

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 6):

Mi propuesta es la siguiente: define las funciones como métodos dentro de un objeto, de este modo podrás acceder a ellas mediantes la notación de corchetes:

```js
const functions = {
  doSetLibraryTreeData: function ([d1,d2,d3]){
    console.log('Ejecutando doSetLibraryTreeData con', d1,d2,d3)
  },
  doSetSource: function ([d1,d2,d3]){
    console.log('Ejecutando doSetSource con', d1,d2,d3)
  },
  doSetFunctionDefinitionList: function ([d1,d2,d3]){
    console.log('Ejecutando doSetFunctionDefinitionList con',d1,d2,d3)
  },
  
  runFn: function (functionName, ...params) {
    this[functionName](params);
  }
};

const batch = [{action: "doSetLibraryTreeData", data: [1,2,3]},
{action: "doSetSource", data: [4,5,6]},
{action: "doSetFunctionDefinitionList", data: [7,8,9]}];

batch.forEach( step => functions[step.action](step.data));
```

Comment: Yo usaría esta opción, aunque implica una modificación del código que podŕia no ser muy atractiva.

Comment: @Emeeus ¿Usas Linux? la errata de poner la tilde en la R sólo la puedo generar en Ubuntu.

Comment: si si, ubuntu, la ŕ ya es una marca registrada, me pasa siempre y como no tengo corrector queda.

Answer (score 3):

Una posible forma es usando `eval`:

```js
const func = [{action: "doSetLibraryTreeData", data: [1,2,3]},
{action: "doSetSource", data: [4,5,6]},
{action: "doSetFunctionDefinitionList", data: [7,8,9]}];


function doSetLibraryTreeData(data){
    console.log(data)
}
function doSetSource(data){
    console.log(data)
}
function doSetFunctionDefinitionList(data){
    console.log(data)
}

func.forEach(f=>{
    eval(f.action)(f.data);
})
```

El uso de eval no es recomendado, pero para ejecutar código como string no hay muchas mas opciones. Hay mucha discusión sobre porque no es recomendado, sugiero leer [esta pregunta en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).

Comment: Aviso: El uso de eval se considera **prohibido** por cualquier purista

Comment: @PabloLozano es verdad, en cuanto a la peligrosidad, es algo bastante relativo, sobre todo si es ejecutado en un navegador. La principal desventaja en un navegador sería la performance y la legibilidad. Yo lo evitaría pero principalmente por la legibilidad del código. Igualmente en este caso no hay muchas mas opciones.

Comment: Yo no lo uso nunca, pero no es una opción directamente inválida. Así que voto positivo y dejo el comentario, el OP que decida lo que más le conviene.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153883/cual-es-la-forma-mas-r%c3%a1pida-de-ejecutar-c%c3%b3digo-string-de-javascript-eval-new